# No resource identifier found for attribute 'paddingEnd' in Package 'android'

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml, android-support-library

I have a problem with the XMl file in v17/mr-media_route_list_item.xml.

I keep getting this error and have not found a solution yet!

Here is a [printshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKVOS.png) of the XML and the Problems*

XML CODE BELOW :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2013 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
              android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                  android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
                  android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
                  android:duplicateParentState="true">

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:singleLine="true"
                  android:ellipsize="marquee"
                  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                  android:duplicateParentState="true" />

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:singleLine="true"
                  android:ellipsize="marquee"
                  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                  android:duplicateParentState="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the actual xml as part of your question.

Comment: What is your Target Api and Min Api?

Comment: in the manifest file for this library the minSdkVersion = 7. There is no max SDK Version declared

Comment: @Emmanuel I added the printshot just so you see in which lines the xml fails

Comment: @Jedil I will install SDK version 7 see if anything changes.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`android:paddingStart` and `android:paddingEnd` were added in API Level 17. Your build target (e.g., Project > Properties > Android in Eclipse) will need to be API Level 17 or higher for those to be recognized.

Comment: Yep, you inadvertently fixed a similar issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare What's with backwards compatibility?

Comment: @Niklas: RTL layout support did not exist prior to API Level 17. You would have to manage that yourself.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hmm it is just weird that when I use [android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml), which definitely uses `android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"` it seems to work for < 17.

Comment: @Niklas: "which definitely uses" -- only on newer devices. The contents of that resource have changed over the years and API levels.